# Column Name checking using script task in ssis

Tags: sql-server-2012, excel-2010, ssis-2012, msbi, foreach-loop-container

Source folder contains multiple excel files with same metadata. Our requirement is all excel files should have all the required columns so How check all required columns are present in Excel files or not through Script Task in SSIS?

Comment: You have taged `ssas`. Didn't you mean to tag `ssis`? Its a good question by the way.